# Kendo grid datasource

Tags: javascript, angularjs, kendo-ui, dropdown

I know what i am asking about is weird but, I have a grid that contains 8 rows. And one of its column has dropDownListEditor. I wanna ask, Is there any possiblity to set a unique datasource in each row for the drop down list editor.

Below is my case, e.g.

Row 1 contains

```
[{ "ID": 1, "Fruit": "Banana" },  
{ "ID": 2, "Fruit": "Mango" },  
{ "ID": 3, "Fruit": "Apple" }]
```

as datasource

Now i want the 2nd row to contain the following datasource for dropdown

```
[{ "ID": 1, "Fruit": "Guava" },
{ "ID": 2, "Fruit": "Lichi" }]
```

Is it possible?

Hello @Nathan i have created a grid as follows,

`<div id="example" ng-app="KendoDemos">
    <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
        <kendo-grid options="mainGridOptions"></kendo-grid>
    </div>
</div>`

Now written the following code in controller

```
angular.module("KendoDemos", ["kendo.directives"]).controller("MyCtrl", function ($scope, $compile) {
var source = [
    {CategoryID: 1, CategoryName: "Beverages"},
    {CategoryID: 2, CategoryName: "Condiments"},
    {CategoryID: 3, CategoryName: "Coffee"},
    {CategoryID: 4, CategoryName: "Bread"},
    {CategoryID: 5, CategoryName: "Green Tea"},
    {CategoryID: 6, CategoryName: "Expresso"}
];

$scope.dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    pageSize: 20,
    data: products,
    autoSync: true,
    schema: {
        model: {
            id: "ProductID",
            fields: {
                ProductID: {editable: false, nullable: true},
                ProductName: {validation: {required: true}},
                UnitPrice: {type: "number", validation: {required: true, min: 1}}
            }
        }
    }
});

$scope.ddlDataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({type: "odata", data: source});
$scope.categoryDropDownEditor = function (container, options) {
    var editor = $('<input kendo-drop-down-list required k-data-text-field="\'CategoryName\'" k-data-value-field="\'CategoryID\'" k-data-source="ddlDataSource" data-bind="value:' + options.field + '"/>').appendTo(container);
};

$scope.mainGridOptions = {
    dataSource: $scope.dataSource,
    pageable: true,
    height: 550,
    toolbar: ["create"],
    columns: [{field: "ProductName", title: "Product Name"}, {
        field: "Category",
        title: "Category",
        width: "180px",
        editor: $scope.categoryDropDownEditor,
        template: "#=Category.CategoryName#"
    }, {field: "UnitPrice", title: "Unit Price", format: "{0:c}", width: "130px"}, {
        command: "destroy",
        title: " ",
        width: "150px"
    }],
    editable: true
};
```

});

Now you can see in the link [dojo.telerik.com/erImu/2], the list contains Beverages, Condiments etc in all the rows. I want it to contain in only first row, otherwise it must contain TEA only.

Comment: Please post what you have tried so far to solve this problem. Your current question is off-topic on SO.

Comment: Now you can see in the link [http://dojo.telerik.com/erImu/2], the list contains Beverages, Condiments etc in all the rows. I want it to contain in only first row, otherwise it must contain TEA only.

Comment: @HarshSharmaKhandal Please **[edit]** all of that information into your question.